# Why do I have a crash while saving parent context?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func save(handler: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void, completion: ((Error?)-> Void)? = nil) {
    if let rootContext = rootContext {
        let localContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        localContext.parent = rootContext
        localContext.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
        handler(localContext)
        guard localContext.hasChanges else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(nil)
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            try localContext.save()
            try localContext.parent?.save() //here, line 65 in CoreDataManager
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(nil)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("❌ Core Data Save Error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is report from Firebase:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I am not an expert on CoreData, however to me, it looks like a threading issue.

A simple solution that you could try would be to wrap your parent context's save call in the [performAndWait(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506364-performandwait) method, like so:

```swift
func save(handler: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void, completion: ((Error?)-> Void)? = nil) {
    if let rootContext = rootContext {
        let localContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        localContext.parent = rootContext
        localContext.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
        handler(localContext)
        guard localContext.hasChanges else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(nil)
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            try localContext.save()
            localContext.parent?.performAndWait {
                try localContext.parent?.save()
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(nil)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("❌ Core Data Save Error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```